# How can I group a dataframe, then summarize a total number for each group, then divide by the number of items in that group?

Tags: r

I used the Group_by function to give me the total sum of amounts by prod_cnt.  But now I want to get the average amount per prod_cnt (average/prod_cnt) by prod_cnt group.  When I try to divide by count = n(), it just returns (+) signs.  How can I get this to work?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data and the code you're working on so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 0):

1. don't nest calls to `summarize`, just include a singgle call and multiple comma-delimited named arguments.
2. use `n()` instead of `count=n()`.

Untested code:

```
library(dplyr)
HW_data_File %>%
  group_by(prod_cat) %>%
  summarize(
    Total_Sale = sum(amount),
    count = n(),
    Per_amount = sum(amount) / n()
  )
```

In order to not recalculate things (likely not a factor, but just for pedagogy), you can do:

```
HW_data_File %>%
  group_by(prod_cat) %>%
  summarize(
    Total_Sale = sum(amount),
    count = n()
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Per_amount = Total_Sale / count
  )
```